# Custom Canonical Tag in Magento 2 Category with Magework seosuite

Tags: magento2, category, custom, canonical

I try to show custom canonical for category with Magework seosuite, but this function I think that not is possible. 
Is there a way to do this, maybe with an extension or plugin of this module ? Thank in advance.  ( Magento 2.3.2)